# Swipe between fragments in android bottom bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, swipe, bottomnavigationview

I'm using [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html) and I'm trying to swipe between fragments, in tapLayout we use `setupWithViewPager()` is there any way to implement swipe in BottomNavigationView like this ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: explain your question properly

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't think you can implement such view with `BottomNavigationView` (unless you pragmatically selected BottomNavigationView items when  a fragment has been selected ). However, the good news is, you can always put the `TabLayout` at the bottom of the layout!

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way to implement swipe in `BottomNavigationView` like this ?

According to Material design guidelines, `BottomNavigationView` is not supposed to support swipe behavior. But i doubt why you stick with `BottomNavigationView`?  You can always use `TabLayout` in the bottom of your parent Layout. `TabLayout` also supports custom views, so there is not limits to implement any behavior. cheers :)